# Keep text inside a textview centered during textsize animation

Tags: android, textview

I am trying to animate the text inside a TextView to grow and change from black to green. The color change works perfectly, and the text size animates between the right sizes, but the text increases in size from the top left point. I would like the text to increase in size from the center. I have tried using `.setGravity(Gravity.Center)`, `.setPivotY()`and `.setPivotX()`, and a few other solutions but nothing seems to be working. Also tried using. `TranslateY` but that seems to move the entire TextView rather than the just the text inside and was getting messy resetting the text position after.

```
    Textview tv_CurrentWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_currentWord);
    final float defaultTextSize = tv_CurrentWord.getTextSize();
        final float finalTextSize = defualtTextSize* 1.2f;
        final float g = 155;
        if (mValueAnimator.isRunning()){
            mValueAnimator.cancel();
            tv_CurrentWord.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, defaultTextSize);
            tv_CurrentWord.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
        mValueAnimator.removeAllUpdateListeners();
        mValueAnimator.setDuration(200);
        mValueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                float animatedValue = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                tv_CurrentWord.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, (finalTextSize-defaultTextSize)*animatedValue+defaultTextSize);
                int color = Color.rgb(
                        0,
                        (int) (g*animatedValue)
                        ,0);
                tv_CurrentWord.setTextColor(color);

            }
        });
        mValueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
            {
                mCurrentWord = "";
                tv_CurrentWord.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 
                defaultTextSize);
                tv_CurrentWord.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv_CurrentWord.setText(mCurrentWord);
            }
        });
        mValueAnimator.start();
```

and the XML. The LinearLayout container was a recent addition to try to keep the text centered, but I am not sure it is needed.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/current_word_height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/rl_players_and_scores"
        android:id="@+id/ll_current_word_container">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_currentWord"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="40sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post two images for side by side comparison?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring this out. Posting here for anyone else who might have the same question. I used `.setTranslationY` and `.setY`. The XML LinearLayout wrapper around the TextView was important because it allowed the TextView to move without throwing off other elements in the parent layout that were positioned off of it. `.setTranslationY` was used to offset the increasing text size in the TextView. Since `.setTextSize(px)` and `.setTranslationY(px)` both take pixels the Y translation just had to be half the change in text size. `.setY()` was used in the animation end, or on restart of the animation to reset the TextView to the original position. `.setTranslationX` was not needed because the text actually stays centered horizontally during the animation.

```
    Textview tv_CurrentWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_currentWord);
    float currentWordYPosition = tv_CurrentWord.getY();
    final float defaultTextSize = tv_CurrentWord.getTextSize();
    final float finalTextSize = defualtTextSize* 1.2f;
    final float g = 155;
    if (mValueAnimator.isRunning()){
        mValueAnimator.cancel();
        tv_CurrentWord.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 
          defaultTextSize);
        tv_CurrentWord.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        tv_CurrentWord.setY(currentWordYPosition);
    }
    mValueAnimator.removeAllUpdateListeners();
    mValueAnimator.setDuration(200);
    mValueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
            float animatedValue = (float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
            tv_CurrentWord.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 
             (finalTextSize-defaultTextSize)*animatedValue+defaultTextSize);

            tv_CurrentWord.setTranslationY(-1*(finalTextSize- 
              defaultTextSize)*animatedValue/2);
            int color = Color.rgb(
                    0,
                    (int) (g*animatedValue)
                    ,0);
            tv_CurrentWord.setTextColor(color);

        }
    });
    mValueAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation)
        {
            mCurrentWord = "";
            tv_CurrentWord.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 
            defaultTextSize);
            tv_CurrentWord.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tv_CurrentWord.setText(mCurrentWord);
            tv_CurrentWord.setY(currentWordYPosition);
        }
    });
    mValueAnimator.start();
```